# solution for image hover

Tags: html, image, hover, effects

I have this markup:

```
<a href="assets/1.jpg" class="lightbox" rel="group1">
<img src="images/albums/album1/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a>
```

And for each thumbnail I have an hover image (see the thumbnail images [here](http://imageshack.us/g/840/60273155.png/)
)

Normal image is the grayscale and hovered is the colored image.
My question is how to add the hover image markup  properly because I have something like 40 images in my gallery?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a CSS solution? JavaScript? jQuery?

Comment: Whichever is good for my markup...

Comment: Your markup has nothing to do with it. Do you currently use jQuery on your site?

Comment: Yes, for the lightbox and that's why I'm asking for a solution.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that  I don't want to use css hover property for every image that's why I'm asking for some hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Javascript (Jquery or custom code, as you wish) for each image, on the onmousover event. Pass the image source as parameter, and simply append for example a _hover.jpg to the source. On the onmouseout event you remove the tailpice, and thats all.

Just remember, you have to name every hover image with the same ending ("_hover.jpg" in my example), and set the images id to their base name (without the .fileformat and etc)

(you could use JQuery to define additional properties instead of the id)

Something like this:

```
<a href="dummy.html">
    <img src="images/basename.png" id="basename"
         onmouseover="showHint(this)"   
         onmouseout="backHint(this)" />
</a>
```

And the Javascript would be something like below:

```
function showHint(img) {
    img.src = "images/" + img.id + "_hover.png";
}

function backHint(img) {
    img.src = "images/" + img.id + ".png";
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution... But also, can I add a style on each          <img src="images/albums/album1/thumbs/1.jpg" style=" "/> and in the style to add the hover image?

Comment: You mentioned that you don't want to use css, so in this case I'm a bit confused about your comment. In css, you could do this with backgrounds, not <img> tags, but its a bit more painful since you have to write the css for every img/div or whatever. (btw don't use inline styles, instead you should put every style in a separate css file)
The Javascript solution is more compact and more generic, since that simple function can handle unlimited number of images and their hovers.